# Kotlin Unit testing - How to mock component of Companion object?

Tags: kotlin, mockk

If I have a (simplified) class that looks like this:

```
class MyManager @JvmOverloads constructor(/*constructor args*/) : MyManagerInterface {

    @Inject
    lateinit var myLogger: MyLogger

    init {
        component = DaggerLoggerComponent.builder()
                .loggerModule(LoggerModule(internalLogger))
                .build()

        component.inject(this)
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var component: RemoteLoggerComponent
            private set
    }
}
```

When unit testing, how on earth do I mock the component in the companion object?

I've tried all kinds of tricks using Mockito, MockK etc but I come up against several obstacles.

The CUT (class-under-test) is another class that is using the MyManager component to inject its dependencies in its init block like so:

```
init {
        if(applicationContext == null) {
            throw IllegalStateException("Application Context must not be null")
        } else {

            MyManager.component.inject(this)
        }
    }
```

Basically, I'd be happy if the injection does nothing because I can set the dependencies externally for the sake of testing.

All help appreciated.  Including if you think I'm coding this wrong.  I'm relatively new to Kotlin and Dagger.  Thanks.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Basically, using MockK, you need code like that:

```
mockkObject(MyManager)
every { MyManager.component.someOp(...) } returns 5
```

Not sure I understand all the details about the injection. As you said you can disable it.

Comment: My goodness!  That seems to have worked.  Thanks!  I assumed that mockkObject was for mocking kotlin object declarations only.  Obviously not.

Comment: How about the using like this:
`mockkObject(MyManager.Companion)
every { MyManager.CompanionsomeOp(...) } returns 5

`

Comment: Not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Do not forget to unmock companion objects. Otherwise, mocked version shall be used after the current test.

Blocked mocking shall unmock automatically for us:

```
mockkObject(MyManager) {
  every { MyManager.component.someOp(...) } returns 5

  act() 

  verify {
    ...
  }

}
```